# Why do I have to use the code_path argument when logging my model?

Tags: amazon-sagemaker, endpoint, mlflow

I have some code to deploy and train a custom mlflow model, that code lives inside a python/poetry project called "hero_bandit" (I have attached the structure of the project). I upload that model to my mlflow server using the mlflow function log_model:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7SFBv.png)

```
mlflow.pyfunc.log_model(
        "models",
        python_model=model,
        registered_model_name="hero-banner",
        pip_requirements=pip_requirements,
    )
```

When trying to read the model from mlflow and starting some predictions using the following code:

```
loaded_model = mlflow.pyfunc.load_model(model_uri_latest)
```

I get the following error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'hero_bandit'

I already tried adding the code with the model by using the code_path variable like this:

```
mlflow.pyfunc.log_model(
        "models",
        python_model=model,
        registered_model_name="hero-banner",
        pip_requirements=pip_requirements,
        code_path=["hero_bandit"],
    )
```

But that creates an issue when trying to deploy the model to Sagemaker, anyway I could find another solution for this without attaching the module hero_bandit code with the model ?